# data.stackexchange bug

Tags: support, data-explorer

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/92981/

It does not seem to care what the filter is

```
where v.VoteTypeId = 999 -- question accepted by asker
```

All v.VoteTypeId still show in the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just that the rows found are all matching this part of the WHERE clause:

```
and p1.id = 4788735 or p1.parentid = 4788735​​
```

If you comment that out:

```
where v.VoteTypeId = 999
-- and p1.id = 4788735 or p1.parentid = 4788735​​
```

you'll see you get nothing that matches just `v.VoteTypeId = 999`.

Perhaps you intended:

```
where v.VoteTypeId = 999
and   ( p1.id = 4788735 or p1.parentid = 4788735​​ )
```